# Error using Spring authorize tag to check to see if user is logged in?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-security

Trying to test to see if a user is logged in  I am using the following code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>

<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
   YES, you are logged in!
</sec:authorize>
```

But I am getting the following erorr?

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No visible WebSecurityExpressionHandler instance could be found in the application context. There must be at least one in order to support expressions in JSP 'authorize' tags.
        at org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.AuthorizeTag.getExpressionHandler(AuthorizeTag.java:100)
        at org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.AuthorizeTag.authorizeUsingAccessExpression(AuthorizeTag.java:58)
        at org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.AuthorizeTag.doStartTag(AuthorizeTag.java:48)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To use expressions to secure individual URLs, you would first need to set the use-expressions attribute in the  element to true

`<http use-expressions="true">`
[See Spring Security doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#el-access-web)

Answer (score 25):

Setting use-expressions="true" in the http element will work but means all your security settings in both Java code and security contexts must use expression notations. This can be a problem if you are currently using the standard security notations.

To use both expressions and standard notations just declare a new bean in your security context like so -

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
```

Comment: It is not working at least for expressions inside http element in security context.