# Why my Spring app can't recognize, that somebody is allready logged in?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am building a web application using `Spring 3 security`

The login page `myapp.com/login` is accessible without any restrictions.

When I log in there, it allows me to continue to another page `myapp.com/home`.

If I load `myapp.com/login` again, it doesn't know that the user has already logged in during this session but when I change URL to `myapp.com/home` it lets me access it *as the previously logged user*.

I've tried different ways to find out if the user is logged in, but without any success.

The front-end technology I'm using is `JSP`.

I've tried these:

```
    <sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_ANONYMOUS">
        <td><a href="<c:url value="/login"/>">Login</a></td>
    </sec:authorize>
    <sec:authorize ifNotGranted="ROLE_ANONYMOUS">
        <!-- shall go to the homepage or better logout the user? -->
        <td><a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout"/>">Logout</a></td>
    </sec:authorize>

    <sec:authorize var="loggedIn" access="isAuthenticated()"/>

    <c:choose>
      <c:when test="${loggedIn}">
        <td><a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout"/>">Logout2</a></td>
      </c:when>
    </c:choose>
```

The above code does not seem to work. Why is this so?

applicationContext-security.xml

```
<beans xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/login" security="none" auto-config="true"/>
    <security:http pattern="/denied" security="none"/>

    <security:http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/denied" servlet-api-provision="false">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/edit/**" access="ROLE_EDIT"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
        <security:form-login login-page="/login"  authentication-failure-url="/denied"
                             default-target-url="/"/>
        <security:logout  logout-success-url="/login" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="adam" password="adampassword" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
                <security:user name="jane" password="janepassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN"/>
                <security:user name="sue" password="suepassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_EDIT"/>
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

You can check the behavior here:

`http://147.32.204.138:5001/GENEPI/login`

Answer (score 0):

I think your configuration should be something like:

```
<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/home*" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_EDIT"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
    <form-login login-page='/login.jsp'/>
  </http>
```

if anonymous login attempt occurs to /home directory, you sould be redirected to login.jsp. 
In home/, you may have a logout link that href is j_spring_security_logout
Also, you may add new intercept patterns for different roles like

```
<intercept-url pattern="/edit*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_EDIT"/>
```

you can check your logged in user in anywhere of your code like:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, nevertheless it doesn't solve my problem... I've tried `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` ,but then I get `exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.io.IOException: No visible WebSecurityExpressionHandler instance could be found in the application context. There must be at least one in order to support expressions in JSP 'authorize' tags.] with root cause
java.io.IOException: No visible WebSecurityExpressionHandler instance could be found in the application context.

Comment: There must be at least one in order to support expressions in JSP 'authorize' tags.` I've updated my post and security cfg file..you might see, what can cause it...

Comment: Check the docs on how to set up a WebSecurityExpressionHandler, setting the use-expressions attribute to "true" in your <http> XML config. http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#el-access-web

Comment: please refer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481879/error-using-spring-authorize-tag-to-check-to-see-if-user-is-logged-in  .Both accepted and other answers may solve your issue.